# How to get geckdriver running with selenium in a local xampp php environment on windows

Tags: php, windows, selenium-webdriver, xampp, geckodriver

I want to use selenium to crawl a complex website with php. It should login and read data, that I want to put in my database. So, easy use.

What I tried:

- I installed Windows
- I installed the actual Xampp with the regular features
- i downloaded geckodriver.exe
- i downloaded composer
- i installed php-webdriver/webdriver (composer require...)
- i put geckodriver.exe in C:/xampp/php and put this directory in the path variable
- i tried on cmd, if it is reachable. and it is
- i stopped all windows firewalls
- i put everything in admin mode (file, cmd.. and so on)
- i startet geckodriver on localhost:4444
- it says "listening on http://localhost:4444"
- i checked with "netstat" and its not showing up
- i downloaded selenium server grid then and startet it (on different ports)
- these ports dont show up on netstat also
- then i realized, that i have to do netstat -a to see this an voila: i saw these connections
- chatgpt said then: if i start selenium server grid on a different port (4445) i have to put it in the php file. this is my code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxOptions;

try {
    // Pfad zum WebDriver-Treiber (geckodriver für Firefox)
    $driverPath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'geckodriver.exe';
   var_dump(file_exists($driverPath));
    // Einstellungen für den Firefox-Browser
    $options = new FirefoxOptions();
    // Fügen Sie hier ggf. weitere Optionen für den Firefox-Browser hinzu

    // Starten der Firefox-Instanz
    $capabilities = [
        WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox',
        'moz:firefoxOptions' => $options->toArray(),
        'wdalocal:hostname' => '192.168.178.93', // oder die IP-Adresse des Selenium Servers
        'wdalocal:port' => 4445, // der von Ihnen angegebene alternative Port
    ];
    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($driverPath, $capabilities);

    // Beispiel für die Verwendung:
    $driver->get("https://www.google.com"); // Webseite aufrufen

    // Warten auf das Laden einer bestimmten Elementklasse
    $wait = new Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverWait($driver, 10);
    $element = $wait->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::name('q')));
    $element->sendKeys('Selenium WebDriver');
    $element->submit();

    // Weitere Crawling-Aktionen hier...

    $driver->quit(); // Browser schließen
} catch (\Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException $e) {
    echo "Fehler: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The file is found. I tried it with a running `geckodriver` and without (as I read, that selenium starts the `geckodriver` if needed).

I tried different browser version that marked as compatible and I also tried the `msedgedriver`. always the same result.

but I ALWAYS get this:

```
bool(true)
Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\Internal\UnexpectedResponseException: JSON decoding of remote response failed. Error code: 4 The response: '' in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdriver_test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Exception\Internal\UnexpectedResponseException.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webdriver_test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.php(334): Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\Internal\UnexpectedResponseException::forJsonDecodingError(4, '') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\webdriver_test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.php(129): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\webdriver_test\index.php(23): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdriver_test\vendor\php-webdriver\webdriver\lib\Exception\Internal\UnexpectedResponseException.php on line 19
```